# Angular binding not working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, data-binding

I have this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YJQx6/) (which won't work, I don't know why. Will be glad if someone would help to fix it). The code in the fiddle is:

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="testApp">
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <span>kid name is {{kids[0].name}}</span><br />
        <input type="text" ng-model="kids[0].name" value={{kids[0].name}} > <br />
        <span>kid age is  {{kids[0].age}}</span> <br />
        <input type="range" value={{kids[0].age}} >

        <div ng-repeat="kid in kids">
            <br />
            The kid's name is <strong id="name">{{kid.name}}</strong> and his age is {{kid.age}}
            <br />
            <input type="range" value={{kid.age}} >
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

JS:

```
var testApp = angular.module('testApp', []);

testApp.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $http)
{
    $scope.kids = [{"name": "Din", "age": 11}, {"name": "Dina", "age": 17}];
});
```

The problem is that the range (age) input is not binded to the the span above it ("kid age is {{kid.age}}").

Why there is no binding?

Comment: The correct answer, the one from nubinub, was actually downvoted and deleted! The fact is that Angular does its binding with `ng-model` *NOT* with `value`. Plus the fact that the fiddle was not even working (it needed the "No wrap" option, as pointed out by others).

Comment: @vlio20 Take a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `onLoad` to `No Wrap` in `JSFiddle`

Also use `ng-model` in input field for binding with the angularjs

change

```
 <input type="range" value={{kid.age}} >
```

to

Take a look at this

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YJQx6/2/)**

```
<body ng-app="testApp">
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
    <span>kid name is {{kids[0].name}}</span><br />
    <input type="text" ng-model="kids[0].name" value={{kids[0].name}} > <br />
    <span>kid age is  {{kids[0].age}}</span> <br />
    <input type="text" value={{kids[0].age}} >

    <div ng-repeat="kid in kids">
        <br />
        The kid's name is <strong id="name">{{kid.name}}</strong> and his age is {{kid.age}}
        <br />
        <input type="range" ng-model="kid.age" value="{{kid.age}}">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, the fiddle you posted not working (there is still no binding).

Comment: also use ng-model in input field for binding with the angularjs

Comment: Not really relevant, but this fiddle uses Angular 1.0.2 instead of 1.2.1... don't get why sanitize and resource should be added

Answer (score 2):

Your fiddle was configured incorrectly. You should select "No wrap in " below the AngularJs version.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/NmHQr/) is the updated fiddle.

In addition to the change in setting, you also need to add `ng-model` to the range input like @nubinub suggested.

```
<input type="range" ng-model="kid.age" value="{{kid.age}}">
```

Comment: why should I add it? for the text input it is working without it.

Comment: The `value` is redundant, only `ng-model` is needed.